# How to create semi transparent linear gradient background and border using css?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am looking to achieve design similar to shown below:

[image]

It has a rounded border (ie., using border-radius), which is has gradient colour from left to right, which is as well semi transparent.

It also has background, which too has semi transparent background gradient.

I tried below ways:

[Creating semi-transparent borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252119/creating-semi-transparent-borders)

[CSS linear-gradient with semi-transparent borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511103/css-linear-gradient-with-semi-transparent-borders)

[Button gradient borders with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868069/button-gradient-borders-with-transparent-background)

JS Fiddle with code that I have tried so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/xobcr0h7/4/

```css
body {
  background:black;
  --border: 5px;
}

div.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  
  /*try 1*/
  
  /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15));*/
    
    /*try 1*/
    
    /*try 2*/
   
   /*border: var(--border) solid transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255, 1), rgb(255, 255, 255, 1)), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.2)) center center /calc(100% + (var(--border) * 2)) calc(100% + (var(--border) * 2));
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    margin: 10px auto;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;*/
    
    /*try 2*/
    
    /*try 3*/
     background: linear-gradient(white, white) padding-box,
        linear-gradient(to right, red, blue) border-box;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    /*try 3*/
    
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Sign Up</div>
```

But they all have solid colors or without border radius. I am trying to achieve something that has both with semitransparent background and border.

Comment: You can use [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) or try one of the online creation tools for CSS glass effects like [CSS Glassmorphism Generator](https://css.glass/).

Comment: Yes, backdrop-filter can be used, but here, if you look at the button's background, it fades with white towards right. It's not a single colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496204/border-gradient-with-border-radius) to create the gradient border and the remaining should be easy

```css
button {
  --b: 5px;  /* border thickness */
  --r: 20px; /* radius */
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(255 255 255/50%); /* background color with alpha */
  border-radius: var(--r);
}
button::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: calc(-1*var(--b));
  padding: var(--b);
  border-radius: calc(var(--b) + var(--r));
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,red,green); /* gradient border */
  opacity: .5; /* alpha for border */
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,#000,#ccc);
}
```

```html
<button>A button</button>
```

Comment: So awesome. The CSS hacker has struck again. I just had to play around with it a bit to even figure out what's going on. This should go straight to the Wiki on how to make a gradient border in 2023.

Comment: @Ferris I already made a wiki for gradient border with all the possible ways ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496341/8620333

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a color with an alpha value such as `rgba`, `hsla` or `hex` with 4 or 8 digits. The alpha sets a transparency to a color:

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}


/* for demonstration purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, black 40%, pink);
}

div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  border-radius: 2em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div>SING UP</div>
```

Comment: Thanks tacoshy. But the border doesn't have gradient and semi transparent effect here.

Comment: reduce the alpha until it has the transparency you want

Comment: Borders can't have gradients... You will have to work hard around that like with SVG's 9-point borders or something

Comment: @somethinghere the border has no gradient. The gradient comes from the background in the images which will work fine using a border-color with an low alpha value.

Comment: I love your enthusiasm, but if the OP tells you there's a gradient...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it meets your expectations, but it was the best I could achieve. Anyway, there are 3 CSS rules needed. One for the button itself, one for the button gradient and then one for the button border. For gradient and border the pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` can be used. In the html part the `div` container as well as the `span` are only for demonstation purposes and are not really needed.

### The button body

There is actually not much to say about this. First, give the button the basic design. The `background` property is only for fine tuning and if you want to blur everything behind the button you can use `backdrop-filter`. The only important thing is to set `position: absolute` or `position: relative`, so that it works perfectly with the pseudo elements.

```
div.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
    backdrop-filter: blur(1.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1.5px);
}
```

### The button gradient

I think most of it is probably self-explanatory. As already mentioned, the pseudo element `::after` is used for the gradient effect. Again, it's important to set `position:absolute` to make things work. The `opacity` property is optional and only there for fine tuning. To avoid overlaying the button text, a negative `z-index` must also be used.

```
div.button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(164, 164, 164, 0.9));
    opacity: 0.85;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

### The button border

Obviously the hardest part. For the border, the pseudo element `::before` is used at last. As before, it's important to set `position:absolute` and again, the `opacity` property is optional and only there for fine tuning. So how is this border made? By using the `background-image` property to which a mix of `linear-gradient` and `radial-gradient` (for the corners) is applied. But, to simplify things, I used CSS variables for the finally snippet. **I first became aware of this technique through an [article](https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/) by [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/author/chriscoyier/).**

```
div.button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image:
        radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, transparent 13px - 2px), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 11px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 13px, transparent 13px), 
        linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)), 
        radial-gradient(circle at 0% 100%, transparent 11px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 11px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 13px, transparent 13px), 
        linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)), 
        radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, transparent 11px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 11px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 13px, transparent 13px), 
        linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)), 
        radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0%, transparent 11px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 11px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 13px, transparent 13px), 
        linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
    background-size: 13px 13px, calc(100% - 26px) 2px, 13px 13px, 2px calc(100% - 26px);
    background-position: top left, top center, top right, center right, bottom right, bottom center, bottom left, center left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

### A working snippet

Enough written, so here is a working example. As already said, for the sake of simplicity I used mostly CSS variables for the button design. Finally, I hope this helps and you might be able to do something with it.

```css
body {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

span {
    color: #773f66;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #eb7e9b, #e078af, #b971a5, #7c5173);
}

/* BUTTON RELATED CSS */

/* button vaiables */

.button {
    /* button width */
    --btn-width: 120px;
    /* button height */
    --btn-height: 50px;
    /* button blurring */
    --btn-blur: 1.5px;    
    /* button background (fine tuning - optional) */
    --btn-background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
    /* button gradient start color */
    --btn-gd-start-col: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    /* button gradient end color */
    --btn-gd-end-col: rgba(164, 164, 164, 0.9);
    /* button gradient additional opacity (optional) */
    --btn-gd-opacity: 0.85;
    /* button border color 1*/
    --btn-bd-col-1: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    /* button border color 2*/
    --btn-bd-col-2: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    /* button border additional opacity (optional) */
    --btn-bd-opacity: 0.5;
    /* button border radius */
    --btn-bd-radius: 13px;
}

/* button body */

div.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: var(--btn-width);
    height: var(--btn-height);
    border-radius: var(--btn-bd-radius);
    background: var(--btn-background);
    backdrop-filter: blur(var(--btn-blur));
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(var(--btn-blur));
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: white;
}

/* button gradient */

div.button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: var(--btn-width);
    height: var(--btn-height);
    border-radius: var(--btn-bd-radius);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--btn-gd-start-col), var(--btn-gd-end-col));
    opacity: var(--btn-gd-opacity);
    z-index: -1;
}

/* button border */

div.button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: var(--btn-width);
    height: var(--btn-height);
    background-image:
        radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, transparent calc(var(--btn-bd-radius) - 2px), var(--btn-bd-col-1) calc(var(--btn-bd-radius) - 2px), var(--btn-bd-col-1) var(--btn-bd-radius), transparent var(--btn-bd-radius)), 
        linear-gradient(to right, var(--btn-bd-col-1), var(--btn-bd-col-2)), 
        radial-gradient(circle at 0% 100%, transparent calc(var(--btn-bd-radius) - 2px), var(--btn-bd-col-2) calc(var(--btn-bd-radius) - 2px), var(--btn-bd-col-2) var(--btn-bd-radius), transparent var(--btn-bd-radius)), 
        linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--btn-bd-col-2), var(--btn-bd-col-2)), 
        radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, transparent calc(var(--btn-bd-radius) - 2px), var(--btn-bd-col-2) calc(var(--btn-bd-radius) - 2px), var(--btn-bd-col-2) var(--btn-bd-radius), transparent var(--btn-bd-radius)), 
        linear-gradient(to left, var(--btn-bd-col-2), var(--btn-bd-col-1)), 
        radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0%, transparent calc(var(--btn-bd-radius) - 2px), var(--btn-bd-col-1) calc(var(--btn-bd-radius) - 2px), var(--btn-bd-col-1) var(--btn-bd-radius), transparent var(--btn-bd-radius)), 
        linear-gradient(to top, var(--btn-bd-col-1), var(--btn-bd-col-1));
    background-size: var(--btn-bd-radius) var(--btn-bd-radius), calc(100% - (var(--btn-bd-radius) * 2)) 2px, var(--btn-bd-radius) var(--btn-bd-radius), 2px calc(100% - (var(--btn-bd-radius) * 2));
    background-position: top left, top center, top right, center right, bottom right, bottom center, bottom left, center left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: var(--btn-bd-opacity);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="button">Sign Up</div>
    <span>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ferris. This is great. Exactly what I was looking for :) But compared to other answer, the lines of code is more in this. I like both the answers equally though.

Comment: Never mind, I would also take the other solution. I've never seen it done like this, let alone known it could be done that way.

Answer (score -2):

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <button>SIGN UP</button>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, purple, darkgrey);
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 50%;
  padding: 30px 120px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(14, 30, 37, 0.12) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgba(14, 30, 37, 0.32) 0px 2px 16px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Marko. But I don't think this solves the problem. It just gives box shadow, which is not intended.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it